# How to set rule for 303 redirect?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have internal links like: `http://example.com/payment/`

If to enter this link instead `http://example.com/payment` I get an error 303.

How to configure `.htaccess` for redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this redirect into your `.htaccess` file.

This allows you to redirect your **entire** website to any other domain

```
Redirect 303 / http://example.com/payment/
```

> **Redirecting a URL:** Using Redirect in an .htaccess file enables you to redirect users from an old page to a new page without having to
>   keep the old page. For example, if you use index.html as your index
>   file and then later rename index.html to home.html, you could set up a
>   redirect to send users from index.html to home.html.

**For example:**

```
Redirect /path/to/old/file/old.html http://www.example.com/new/file/new.html
```

You can find more detailed examples [here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-).

Comment: I can not specify a rule for all urls, can I use common rule?

Comment: I need to redirect from `/payment` to `/payment/`

Comment: Did you try /payment and /payment/ in browser? I think both meant the same.